# How to wait for any keypress (global), or mouse click (on certain application windows) - Python

Tags: python, input, keyboard, wait, mouselistener

I have a simple python script that goes something like this:

```py
user_input = ''
application = ''

print('press any key or click on any application...')

WAIT_FOR_INPUTS() # this is the part I'm stuck on

if key:
     print(f'You pressed {key}.')
if click:
     print(f'You clicked on {application}')
```

I'm lost in pygame, pyautogui, win32gui, pynput and I don't know which module will solve my problem. I'm in python3 so I can't use raw_input(). If anybody knows how to help me I'd really appreciate it since this is one of the last hurdles to a project I'm excited about.

Comment: If a reply answers your question, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the keyboard module:

```py
import keyboard

def detect_pressed_key():
    print("Press any key to continue...")
    keyboard.read_key()  # Waits for a key press

detect_pressed_key()
print("Key pressed!")
```